# How to solve database initialization error?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have been testing out different things and have concluded that the following error is the reason my database will not initialize and throws an exception. The exception occurs when I reference the database and initialize it. My Web.config connection string is fine as you can see. I am using Entity Framework 6, MSSQL, and C#. Any help would be appreciated.

Exception:

```
Cannot open database \"xxx\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'xxxx'.
```

Connection String:

```
<add name="WebDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=WebDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Code:

```
private SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext();

public ViewMethod Method()
{
  var students = from s in db.Students select s; //EXCEPTION IS THROWN HERE
}
```

Comment: " The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'PC\\USER'"  <-- very explicit

Answer (score 0):

You should mention `userid` and `password` in connection string

```
<add name="WebDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=WebDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=xyz;pwd=top$secret;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is not in the format required by EF, it should actually look similiar to this:

```
<add name="XYZ" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModEntity.csdl|res://*/ModEntity.ssdl|res://*/ModEntity.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=SomeServer;Initial Catalog=SomeCatalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Entity;Password=SomePassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: That type of connection string is used for model first.  If you are using code first, the connection string in the question is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Also use linq query.

```
var students = db.Students;     

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="WebDBContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ModelName.csdl|res://*/Models.ModelName.ssdl|res://*/Models.ModelName.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=servername;initial catalog=databasename;user id=username;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

replace the ModelName to your Model and change connections on your db.